# The markings of Mictal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I found this sketch in the notes old Alembic took while exploring the ruins of the ancient city of Mictal. The man must have copied some writing he encountered among the ruins.

[image]

If only I could figure out what these markings mean...

---

**UPDATE - hints**

> It is a set of instructions.

(I'll give it another week before I post the next.)

Comment: I can't decide if those are anagrams or ciphers.

Comment: @Raystafarian It might be anything - a map, a code, a religious pattern or even a recipe for the king's favorite tomato soup!

Comment: is it the 'short circuit' robot - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Circuit_(1986_film)?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, but perhaps it may have something to do with robots or computer programs

Comment: @YehudaShapira can we get a hint on this one?

Comment: @Z.Dailey Sure thing.

Comment: I've got it! Now to type it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were trying to communicate...

> **bubble sort**! The balls are weights that need to be sorted. The big box explains how to weigh things and that you need to put the heavier one on the right; the box under that goes through one iteration, after which the heaviest weight is on the right. The bottom set of boxes is all of the iterations.

Here's a picture explaining everything (cut into three parts since Imgur wasn't happy with a 5 MB image):

> [image: mictal top]
>  [image: mictal middle]
>  [image]

Comment: Wow! I like the way you made everything clear with the colors